# Behaviour of <link rel=alternate> in browsers

Tags: html, http, rest, hateoas

I am a bit confused about the behavior of `<link rel="alternate" ...>` in browsers and i am looking for some clarification. Let's use the following code for illustration:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="a.css" type="text/css" 
              title="Main Stylesheet">
        <link rel="alternate stylesheet" href="b.css" type="text/css" 
              title="Alternative Stylesheet">
        <link rel="alternate" href="fr.pdf" hreflang="fr" type="application/pdf" 
              title="Alternative document in French">
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

When this code runs in a modern browser (e.g. Firefox v27.01), the browser parses the above HTML document and then downloads the stylesheets, a.css and b.css. The former is used to apply the style to the document. However, b.css is available through the 'View > Page Style' menu of the said browser. So, clearly the parser in Firefox is able to recognize the "alternative" stylesheet and in this case decided to download it.

One can read at [W3C > HTML5 > 4.8.4.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#rel-alternate) that the outcome of parsing those `<link>`s are **basically** hyperlinks referencing the respective document. In the case of stylesheet, the browser is smart enough to download it as well. But, for the other alternate document (fr.pdf) in our example, it looks like Firefox does not download it and if it links it, it is not visible anywhere. I tested in Chrome (v.33.0.1750.117), Opera (v.19.0.1326.63), IE (v.10.0.9200.16798) and could observe same thing (i.e. no visible artifact that the fr.pdf has been linked). So, as all those modern browsers behave like this, it looks like I have misunderstood the meaning of "alternate" relationships:) Would someone have an explanation for me of how they are intended to be used? My belief is that in a RESTful manner, user-agents should be able to (hyper)link all the `<link>`s in order to navigate that web.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure that PDF is readable by the browser as a StyleSheet, which is what that code seems to suggest/try to accomplish. `<link rel=alternate>` only loads the file, though, so you'd need CSS to determine when to display the alternate file.

Comment: @TylerH Thanks for the prompt reply however, the pdf link has only an "alternate" relationship. It is not used with stylesheets. b.css has an "alternate stylesheet" relationship. Perhaps you mixed the lines because of my poor indentation :)

Comment: I think then since you have `lang=fr` declared, you'd need to try loading the site with your browser's language set to fr. Have you tried this?

Comment: Yes, but changing that preferred language of the browser to say FR would only have the intended effect of setting the "Accept-Language" to FR when requesting the HTML document and server-side can react to that. For the sake of experimentation, i tried it out and there is no change.

Answer (score 3):

The `<link>` element does indeed identify external documents that are related to the current document. And the `rel` attribute specifies the nature of that relationship. In the specific case of `rel="alternate stylesheet"` (some) browsers can do something specific with the link. In particular, Firefox and Opera give the user a chance to select this "alternate" stylesheet from the application's menu. See, e.g., the screen shot

[image]

from [this article](https://www.sitepoint.com/rel-html-attribute/).

In order to apply that style sheet, the browser needs to download it.

In the more general case of `rel="alternate"` (not a stylesheet), then the browser won't know anything useful to do with the related link. Therefore, as far as the browser is concerned, there's no need to download it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, how about the fact in the example above that the mime type is specified and modern browsers know how to handle that. So, at the very minimum they can hyperlink it for navigation (e.g. in a menu somewhere like they do with CSS and you've shown above). So, i don't agree with the part in your answer that they don't know what to do with the related link.

Comment: Stephen, you could be right. When I get more time I will check the source of Firefox parser and report here. Hopefully, someone with that kind of knowledge might answer to us sooner.